# How can I add another repository in git?

Tags: git, github

I have a GitHub repository that I push my data in it. I would like to add another remote repository to push my data at the same time.

For example;

```
git push origin master
git push {another origin} master
```

Anybody know if it is possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add an additional remote using the following syntax:

```
git remote add remotename https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

You can then push to it (assuming you have the permissions) using:

```
git push remotename remotebranch
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mureinik

Answer (score 4):

You have to add another remote:

```
git remote add another-origin <url>
git push another-origin master
```

You can replace `another-origin` with the remote name you want. Also, replace the `<url>` with your remote url you want to add.

GitHub has [a nice guide](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/) about this. About working with remotes in general, you can read more [here](https://help.github.com/categories/managing-remotes/).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ionică Bizău